# Can I directly instantiate an interface using Java reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm dealing with a contractor's code. For whatever reason he has made a series of "constants" files that are all interfaces. They look like this:

```
interface SomeTypeConsts {
    public static class SomeSubTypeA {
        public static final String CONSTANT_A = "foo";
        public static final String CONSTANT_B = "bar";
    }
    public static class SomeSubTypeB {
        public static final String CONSTANT_A = "baz";
    }
}
```

and so forth. There are no unimplemented/abstract methods, the files just contain nested classes some arbitrary level deep, and static final Strings for the constants. I cannot modify the contractor's code at this time.

I'm writing a test framework and I need an **instance** of one of these constants interfaces. All of them follow the above pattern, but my method needs to support all of them and not just one in specific.

I tried instantiating the interface using Reflection like this:

```
clazz.newInstance() // where clazz is Class<SomeTypeConsts>
```

But it threw a `java.lang.InstantiationException`.

All of the questions here on SO say that you need to implement the interface first, then use that instance. And if I knew ahead of time which const interface it was, I could easily do `SomeTypeConsts consts = new SomeTypeConsts(){};`. But I haven't been able to figure out how to do this with reflection, when all I have to work with is the `Class<SomeTypeConst>`.

Given an interface Class reference, with no abstract methods to be overwritten/implemented, how can I instantiate an instance of it using reflection?

Comment: Look up the "Constant Interface Antipattern". Your contractor is not a good programmer.

Comment: Yeah I know. My contractor is an idiot, but I have no input into that.

Comment: You do not need an instance of these interfaces--it's 100% pointless. As these are static, they'll be resolved at compile-time. You can (and should) write `SomeTypeConsts.SomeSubTypeA.CONSTANT_A`.

Comment: Can you show the code where you *need* the instance of the interface? I'm sure there is another way to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: You can't directly instantiate them, but you _can_ create a mock implementation using Java's [Proxy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) class. But as the others have pointed out, there's probably no need to do so. You can access the classes' static fields without an instance, and the instances won't have any methods other than the ones defined by Object.

Comment: It does not make sense to instantiate something that by definition is not instantiatable

Comment: I hope that you don't need an instance just to be able to call getClass() later i.e. a "sample object".

Comment: Noob question, since I am still a student, but are string constants bad form in terms of programming? I can see it being bad code the way you describe it as it does sound like hell to put it in a test harness.

Comment: @SomeStudent -- It's not the string constants that are the bad practice. It's the fact that they were put into an interface rather than a class. This is a particular antipattern called the "Constant Interface Antipattern;" you should read up on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html) (emphasis mine):

> This type has no instance variables, and typically declares one or more abstract methods; otherwise unrelated classes can implement the interface by providing implementations for its abstract methods. **Interfaces may not be directly instantiated.**

And, from [the Javadoc of `Class.newInstance()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance()):

> [throws] `InstantiationException` - **if this Class represents** an abstract class, **an interface**, an array class, a primitive type, or void; or if the class has no nullary constructor; or if the instantiation fails for some other reason.

You can't instantiate an interface. You can only instantiate (non-abstract) classes which implement it.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this using a JDK proxy for the interface, but it would be entirely pointless: If all you're doing is accessing static members, all of that is resolved without reference to any actual instance of the type in question, either at compile-time (far preferable) or at runtime with some approach like enumerating the fields and filtering on the static ones.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot do that. Interfaces by definition are not instantiable.

Comment: Even with reflection? You can do a lot of stuff that you're "not allowed to do" otherwise with reflection.

Comment: Are you under the impression that I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Perhaps, @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, if you told us what you hope to accomplish someone could provide you a way to do that that would actually work.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a mock object. Not reflection